# How to add System.Diagnostics reference in C# application?

Tags: c#

I am developing small application about PerformanceCounter...i need to add `System.Diagnostics` reference but i am not able to find in Assemblies.

Comment: Which platform? .NET Framework, .NET Core, .NET Standard, something else? Which version?

Comment: All you need to do is `using System.Diagnostics`

Comment: System.Diagnostics is a namespace, not an assembly, it should already be present. Can you tell us why you feel you need to add anything to your references, do you have code that doesn't compile?

Comment: To be fair, the MSDN page does list it as appearing in `System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter.dll`, as well as in `System.dll`. Which is why I asked for the platform.